# Trouble to obtain eigenvectors of a matrix knowing its eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gaussian-elimination

The problem: Being given the matrix:
$$   \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & -1 & -1 \\
        1 & 2 & 1 \\
        -1 & -1 & 0
        \end{bmatrix}$$
and two of its eigenvalues $0,1$. Obtain matrix $P$ (whose columns are associated to the eigenvalues)

My attempts: I know the formula first I use 0 and subtract it from the entries across the diagonal and get:

the same matrix. then I add row 2 to row 3 and get:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & -1 & -1 \\
        1 & 2 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 1
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Then I added row one to row 3, row flipped one and two and got:
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
 and the solution that I got was:

x = $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        -1\\
        1
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

but the book says no, it's:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 \\
        1 \\
        -1
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

For the corresponding lambda =1, after subtracting the diagonals I get:
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & -1 & -1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        -1 & -1 & 0
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Then I added row one and row two, multiplied row one by -1:
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & -1 & 0
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

All I can do here is add row one and three and get:
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
leaving one free variable and well quite honestly it doesn't matter what my answer is from here because I only have two columns for P. Something is seriously wrong I don't know if I am making a logical error in my row operations and happen to be committing a logical no no or what? I have checked over it and I just can't for the life of me figure out the what problem is. Please give a concise explanation. Thank you.

As for eigenvalues being defined only up to a constant I don't understand what you mean by my answer is okay if its negative of the book moreover I lack the proper rows.

Comment: Your inability to do this does not mean you are stupid...

Comment: eigenvectors are only well-defined up to a constant, so if your answer is the negative of the book's answer you're fine

Comment: Okay I will adjust accordingly looks like the community would prefer it but it is how I feel.

Comment: For matrix $A$ with an eigenvalue $\lambda$, if $\mathbf v$ is an eigenvector that satisfies $A\mathbf v = \lambda \mathbf v$, then for non-zero scalar $k$, it is also true that
$$A(k\mathbf v) = \lambda (k\mathbf v)$$
So $k\mathbf v$ is also an eigenvector associated with $\lambda$, but obviously that is linearly dependent to $\mathbf v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvector you obtained and the one in the book differ only in sign, that is by multiplication by $-1$. Both vectors are eigenvectors for eigenvalue $0$ and equally correct answers.

For the other eigenvalue, you just forgot to subtract in the last line. If you correct this you will get two free variables.

Comment: Okay now I see it. Thank you. I don't know why errors like that in the last line always evade me.

Comment: You are welcome. In this case the problem may have been that you thought you were making a more serious error. But, in fact it was just a minor glitch and you seem on a good way to understand the material. :-)